# How to go from one "private void" to other "private void"?

Tags: c#, void, goto

how can i go from `private void turnon` to `private void turnoff` ? I want only know how to go from one void to other. I know i can just make from these two a one private void but i don't want it

```
private void turnon(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Visible = true
}

private void turnoff(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button3.Visible = false
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you trying to toggle between the button being enabled in one method?

Comment: No, i want something like 'goto' (cmd command)

Comment: You mean like, call the method?

Comment: yes, if turnon ends i want to go to turnoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting it to be visible in one event and visible in another, why not use one method like so:

```
private void SwitchState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button3.Visible = !button3.Visible;
}
```

On reading your comments I guess you want to add this line in at the end of your turnon event:

```
turnoff(sender, e);
```

Comment: @KacperSerewis If this worked for you feel free to accept it as an answer so that other people are aware as such

Comment: sorry, i want to do this earlier but stackoverflow keeps saying "you can accept this answer in 2 mins"

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a toggle? If so, you could use the following code.

```
private void toggle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Visible = !button2.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I want to make toggle button, So that it shows/hides the content by clicking that searchButton
Here is my code,

```
    private boolean visible;
    protected  Button SearchButton;

    private void Toggle(){

            if(visible=false){
                DishButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);     
                SpoonButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);     
                cupButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);     
                FridgeButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            }
            else {
                DishButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
                SpoonButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
                cupButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
                FridgeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
                visible=true;
            }
        }
```